# WebDriver in Selenium will "cache" its selecting result?

Tags: java, selenium

Using Selenium WebDriver in Sun JDK 1.6, I've a PageObject provide a method like this

```java
public void function selectDate()
{
     //The HTML Calendar element should be already opened by the caller. 

     //Line X
     this.driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(/*Selector Statement*/)).click();
     //Will cause the founded element disappeared.
}
```

And I wish this method should be resuable. That means I can call it many times in a caller method:

```java
public void function caller()
{
     this.driver.findElement(By.
         cssSelector(/*Selector for showing the HTML Calendar*/)).click();
     po.selectDate();

     this.driver.findElement(By.
         cssSelector(/*Selector for showing the ANOTHER Calendar*/)).click();      
     po.selectDate();
}
```

But an exception will occur

```
Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with;
(... Stack trace...)
    at Line X
```

The stack trace show the error is cause by the line X in the `selectDate()` method.
If I only call the `selectDate()` method once, no exception will be thrown.

The only one reason here I can guess is that WebDriver will "Cache" the selecting results,
so if I select the same element using same CSS selector, it will find the old and disappeared one. Am I right ? Or there're somethings I missed ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you're always using the same `By.cssSelector(/*Selector Statement*/)` in `selectDate()`, you're always selecting the same element.  CBRRacer and I are assuming that you expect your *Selector Statement* to be somehow affected by which calendar you've selected, but that isn't how selectors work.  So if the selector is for a part of the first calendar, it will fail the second time, and if for the second, then it will fail on the first.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way of handling this is look for the displayed property.

```
public void function selectDate()
{
     //The HTML Calendar element should be already opened by the caller. 

     //Line X
     WebElement thisElement = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(/*Selector Statement*/));
     if(thisElement.Displayed)
     {
      thisElement.click();
     }
     //Will cause the founded element disappeared.
}
```

I'm guessing that when you make an Item disappear the element isn't removed from the dom it's just hidden (display:none or show: false).  Which means selenium can still find the element but it just can't interact with it.So if you check for displayed then you know that you can interact with it.

The other option is to catch your selectors to a list or an array and parse the list or array.